# spurious whitespace in \index with fixme package

Tags: spacing, indexing, fixme

Consider the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fixme}
\makeindex
\begin{document}
    Ignorance is strength\index{strength}.
\end{document}
```

Then there will be a white space between “strength” and the full stop. What is the best way to circumvent this problem?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You only really needed to give the first two words of your subject:-).

It had to be a missing `%`,
in this case in the  `fixme` package.

Adding

```
\makeatletter
\def\@wrindex#1{%
  \ifthenelse{\equal{\cmdfx@note@target}{thepage}}{%
    \protected@write\@indexfile{}{\string\indexentry{#1}{\thepage}}}{%
    \protected@write\@indexfile{}{\string\indexentry{#1}{\cmdfx@note@target}}}%<<<
  \endgroup
  \@esphack}
\makeatother
```

Fixes `fixme`

Comment: Thanks. I probably should have found that myself ;-) Anyway, I sent a message to the maintainer of fixme about it.

Answer (score 7):

Thanks for the report. This bug has already been fixed in a new version of FiXme that I basically failed to release for the last 2 years... :-) Keep the faith !

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx, didier!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: This bug is now *officially* and *publicly* fixed (version 4.2 of FiXme is out).

Comment: @Barbara Good to hear from you!

Comment: @Joseph After 5 attempts at reading your comment, I think I finally understand it. I've never used SX before so I failed to grasp the notions of comments vs. answers. Thanks for the hint.